Angular stacktrace not showing TypeScript stack trace in dev mode
I have a project from a 'fuse angular template' hoping to quick start development and not have to write a bunch of components.

clone repo https://github.com/deanhiller/ts-prototype
NOTE: main branch is constantly changing but I will try to keep the exception thrown there but there is always the branch "angularTheme" which I am not working on which throws the exception too.
cd client
npm install
npm run dev (browser opens)
open dev tools console

and when GUI shows, you click sign in and I have it coded to throw and log an exception. The stack trace is a JavaScript one not a TypeScript one. When I do the new project in Angular (same version, 18), it works just fine.  I tried diffing these and porting but in doing so, the stack trace stops working along the way.

What is the process for debugging why this is not working?
How do JavaScript sourcemap and TypeScript sourcemap work?  Should I see the intermediary files somewhere that I can check on?

I have tried base React new project and comparisons and merging to no avail.

oh wow!! OMG.  So, it works when using Observables but using Promise with async/await, it breaks and only shows the javascript stacktrace :( :(.
EDIT: BASE ANGULAR works with stack traces and async/await as I just tested 18.1.0, but for some reason, the template I bought breaks all that and I can't find the setting or what exactly breaks the stack traces from working.
This is really really frustrating as using async/await allows us to create 'synchronous looking code' which is much more readable and maintainable.  This is a huge tradeoff losing typescript stack trace for readability or losing readability to have good stack traces :( .

@sanket I saw you commented on another post about learning observables but what happens when I am using a third party lib that is all async functions?  I prefer the code to read sync(and be async) and have good stack traces.
